# TensorFlow: How to constrain/update only some rows of a variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I have an embedding matrix variable

```
embs = tf.get_variable(name="embs", shape=[total, hidden_size])
```

I want to constrain the norm to be unit

```
embs_unit_norm_op = tf.assign(embs, tf.keras.constraints.unit_norm(axis=1)(embs))
```

But the `embs` matrix is too large, and only some rows changed by the previous gradient applying step. I want to reduce computation by only constraining/updating these 'active' embeddings.

I have a list of row numbers, e.g., `e = [1, 3, 5]`, same as one-hot ID used in embedding lookup. How could I constrain/update only these "active" embeddings?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `tf.scatter_update` or `tf.scatter_nd_update`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. Can you improve your answer by giving examples?